# Conditional statements inside `printf`

Tags: c, printf, conditional-statements

Is there any method to use a conditional statement inside other statements, for example `printf`?

One way is using ternary operator `? :` eg:

```
printf("%d", a < b ? a : b);
```

Is there a method for more complicated conditions?

Comment: Why don't you just evaluate the expression beforehand?

Comment: I wanted to know if c language supports such statements

Comment: What do you mean by "more complicated"? A ternary expression is an expression, and so can be used as a function (any function) argument. If the condition in the ternary expression is "complicated" or not doesn't matter.

Comment: As long as their types match.

Comment: what do mean by much more complicated conditions??

Comment: Have you tried it out? With `printf`, you have to take care that your format specifiers match the arguments' types, but otherwise the arguments of `printf` after the format can be any expression, including the ternary conditional.

Comment: if want 2 statements evaluated based on the condition

Comment: With the ternary operator your expression can be as complicated as you want, e.g: `a < b ? (b > c ? d : e) : f` and you can of course use this expression as a parameter to printf.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need for more complex expressions, the conditional operator is already bad enough. There is no language feature for it. Instead, write a function.

```
printf("%d", compare(a,b)); // good programming, readable code

printf("%d", a<b?(x<y?x:y):(x<y?y:x)); // bad programming, unreadable mess
```

Comment: Ternary operators are pretty normal and when used well make code quite readable and more compact.  On the other hand, having to jump through more methods can make debugging complex systems that much more difficult.  If its a simple if / else type of comparison, go at it and use a ternary, if its nested with complex logic, then sure, use a method.

Comment: @Michael Common sense has to be applied from case to case. There are indeed some cases where the `?:` operator makes code more readable (like switch statements where the only task of each `case` is to assign a value based on a condition), but in the majority of the cases, such as in this example, it actually tends to make code less readable. Therefore, it is an operator to use with care - always consider if other solutions are more readable. Also, unlike `if` statments, the `?:` invokes multiple implicit type promotions, which can cause unexpected problems.

Answer (score 2):

Every conditional statement return `1` or `0`. These values are `int`

So if you do `printf("%d",a>b);` then either `1`(true) or `0`(false) will be printed.

In your example you are using ternary operator `a<b?a:b`.
If condition is true then `a` will be printed else `b`.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot put *statements* into `printf` at all, you only can put *expressions* there.  The ternary operator forms an *expression*.  An expression is basically a tree of operators and operands, however there are a few funny operators allowed, like the ',' comma operator or the '=' assignment operator.  This allows expressions to have side effects.